# How to save Activity State with this

Tags: android, savestate

I'm having a hard time saving the state of my activity so that when the activity is destroyed it can restore where the user last left off. Here is my source code. How do I save and restore it.

```
    public class DorothyTalk extends Activity{
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        int typeBar;
        TextView text1;
        EditText edit;
        Button respond;
        private String name;
        private ProgressDialog progDialog;
        @Override 
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.dorothydialog);
            
            text1 = (TextView)findViewById(com.fttech.da.R.id.dialog);
            edit = (EditText)findViewById(com.fttech.da.R.id.repsond);
            respond = (Button)findViewById(com.fttech.da.R.id.button01);
            
            Talk();
            
        }

        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch(id) {
            case 0:                      // Spinner
                progDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                progDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progDialog.setProgress(100);
                   return progDialog;
            }
            return progDialog;
        }
        public void  Talk(){
            text1.setText("Welcome what is your name?");
            respond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    name = edit.getText().toString();
                    new AsyncTask(){
                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                            try {                 
                             Thread.sleep(1000);             
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                         
                                e.printStackTrace();             
                            }            
                            return null;
                        }
                        @Override         
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            text1.setText("Nice to meet you "+name);
                            dismissDialog(typeBar);
                        }
                        @Override        
                        protected void onPreExecute() { 
                            typeBar = 0;
                            showDialog(typeBar);
                        }
            
                    }.execute((Void)null);
                }
            });
        }
        
    
        public void onBackPressed(){
            int i = Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
            Context localContext = getApplicationContext();
            Intent localIntent = new Intent(localContext, mainMenu.class);
            startActivityForResult(localIntent, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Right now I do not know where to begin. Thanks to who ever can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just override [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // Save away the original text, so we still have it if the activity
        // needs to be killed while paused.
        outState.putString(ORIGINAL_CONTENT, mOriginalContent);
        outState.putInt("MyInt", 1);

    }
```

after that, you can retrieve in onCreate(Bundle) or onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle) (the Bundle populated by this method will be passed to both)

Comment: Okay so i just saved all my text away.. Now the problem is how  to i get the activity to realize where the user is in the problem.. When it first starts it asks your name...After that it says welcome (name) oor something... The problem is how do i get the activity to come back to where the user left off after being destroyed.

Comment: Hmm.... you can save the values of the widgets in the bundle. outState.putString("text1", text1.getText()).  And onCreate() just get the value for the text1 and set it again. Maybe there is another solution... but i guess this solves your problem.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution man.. But how would i save what the user last entered..The program works by on click listeners... How would i save what click the user is on? or how would i recover from a destroy and restore the FULL state of where the user left off , and what onClickListener were they on.

Comment: You have the OnClickEvent in almost all widgets. You could update an attribute with the last widget clicked (keep in mind that you need to store this information during the onSaveInstanceState)... Also, you can also give focus to any widget. This way, you can get the last widget the user updated and give focus (something like editText.setFocusable(boolean)) during the onCreate().

Comment: This is not working, in my case outState is always null in onCreate(Bundle outState)